# The operation can't be completed because the item is in use …

Tags: macos, xcode, mojave

im using Macos Mojave, and some of my Xcode files were locked i guess by the system. So i trashed them and now im not able to clean the Trash. Im getting annoying error The operation can't be completed because the item is in use … Rebooting in safe mode, disabling login items, fixing permissions on disk does not helped. How can i clean my trash?

Comment: Fixing permissions is typically for several years old os. Might you edit this to show you performed these steps in order? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201583

Comment: yes i perormed these steps, https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201583 i was not able to run first aid neither during normal boot, nor in cmd+R because in second case macintoshHD was greydout

Comment: Which files exactly have you trashed? Are you talking Xcode system files? - or is it Xcode projects? (i.e. files that you have created yourself)

Comment: I had a similar issue once. Oddly enough I was able to empty my Trash after I disabled SIP.

Comment: ok, i was able to trash it with rm -rf ~/.Trash

Comment: I wish you these weren't protected files belonging to the system.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the OP’s solution:

The trash can be emptied using:

```
rm -rf ~/.Trash
```

Comment: Does not work for me. Getting error message "Directory not empty"

Comment: This is *NOT* emptying your trash - this is deleting the user's trash folder!  Additionally, this will not override a file in use error.  The *proper* fix is to find out what process has the file open and close it.